How to pass environment variables when executing a Google Cloud Run Job using Node.js or Python client?
I’m trying to execute a Google Cloud Run job and pass environment variables to it, similar to how I would using the gcloud CLI:
gcloud run jobs execute <test-job> --update-env-vars key1=value1,key2=value2

I want to achieve the same functionality using either the Node.js or Python client libraries for Google Cloud Run.
Here’s the auto-generated code snippet for running a job using the Node.js client:
/**
// const overrides = {};

// Imports the Run library
const {JobsClient} = require('@google-cloud/run').v2;

// Instantiates a client
const runClient = new JobsClient();

async function callRunJob() {
  // Construct request
  const request = {
    name,
    // overrides,
  };

  // Run request
  const [operation] = await runClient.runJob(request);
  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  console.log(response);
}

callRunJob();

Reference: RunJob method documentation
How can I modify this code to pass environment variables to the job execution, similar to using --update-env-vars in the gcloud CLI? I’m looking for solutions in either Node.js or Python.

you must pass the override parameters like this

  const request = {
    name: job,
    overrides: {
      containerOverrides: {
        env: [
            {
                name: <envVar.name>,
                value: <envVar.value>,
             }],
      },
    },
  };


It's confusing but it's well-documented.
There are various ways to teach yourself how to do this for any Google service for any method for any language:

Use the API documentation (as you are)
Use e.g. gcloud to create a job and then use describe methods to query the resources to see what's been created.
Append --log-http to any gcloud command to see what REST calls are being made by the commands.
Use APIs Explorer to drill-down into the Cloud Run Admin API methods e.g. projects.locations.jobs.create

NOTE You must create Jobs before you can run them and, it's during create that you can set environment variables.
For Node.JS:
createJob has request of type:
ICreateJobRequest has job of type:
IJob has template of type:
IExecutionTemplate has template of type:
ITaskTemplate has containers an array of type:
protos.google.cloud.run.v2.IContainer has env of type:
IEnvVar which is where you can set name and e.g. value fields.
These would be obtained e.g. from environment variables obtained e.g. process.env.{FOO}
Alternatively, I'll save the drill-down, here's the Container represented using API Explorer which gives the API view.
